# Difference between Window and ApplicationWindow in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.12

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menubar.html

MenuBar is supported in `ApplicationWindow` and not in `Window`.

Following throws an error "Invalid property name: MenuBar"

```
Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 280; height: 280

    menuBar: MenuBar {
          Menu {}
    }
}
```

whereas following works:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 280; height: 280

    menuBar: MenuBar {
          Menu {}
    }
}
```

In the new Qt version 5.12, the default code uses `Window` and not `ApplicationWindow`.

What is the difference between `Window` and `ApplicationWindow`? Which one should be used in which case?

Comment: `Window` is a basic QML type. It is just that - a window. `ApplicationWindow` is part of QtQuick Controls 2 and has similar functionality as `QMainWindow`. Which one to use is up to you. If you need a simple window, use `Window`. If you need the extended functionality, use `ApplicationWindow`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html) is very clear:

> ApplicationWindow is a Window that adds convenience for positioning items, such as MenuBar, ToolBar, and StatusBar in a platform independent manner.

That is, it is an item that inherits from Window but has certain default attributes, it is similar to QMainWindow with respect to QWidget.

When you say: *In the new Qt version 5.12, the default code uses Window and not ApplicationWindow* I suppose you mean that QtCreator uses Window by default in creating projects, that's just because the developers wanted to and there is no science in it, just a choice.

When you should use one or the other depends on when you want to customize and if you are comfortable with the ApplicationWindow structure since as you can see the latter has a predefined structure.

**Note:** There are 2 items called ApplicationWindow <sup>[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html), [2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html)</sup>

Comment: Am thankful to you. Didn't know there were docs mentioning all this.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Well, for a next time you have to read and re-read the documentation since many of the answers are there.

Answer (score 0):

it is just  same comparing QMainWindow with QWidget..
QMainWindows is QWidget that higher level for creating more stuffs for you.. the same happens with ApplicationWindow and Window.